# How to change the drag HTML element with another HTML element?

Tags: html, draggable

Look on this simple [`EXAMPLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/dzsk7311/3/)

I'm trying to change by JS code the HTML element that is being drag to be another HTML element. On this example, when I choose to drag banana, I would like to really drag the Apple instead. How can it be done?

Comment: change the identifier `var drop = data == "drag1" ? "drag2" : "drag1"; var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(drop).cloneNode(true);`

Comment: *Plus when you clone the image you're also cloning the id, that's wrong.*

Comment: 10x for the answer, but what I was really looking for is to change the element that is being drag when it is being drag. I click to drag something, but I want to see while drag something else. How this can be done?

Comment: creates a ghost element and voila https://jsfiddle.net/sg7v9jpw/